# Read PDF from mongoDB and display in HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, base64, gridfs-stream

So I was successfully able to upload a PDF to mongoDB but reading and displaying it is an issue.

**I uploaded the pdf and read it by converting like so:**

```
var buf2 = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
```

**The above gave the pdf in the following format:**

```
JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhlbi1HQikgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDIwIDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQoyIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL1BhZ2VzL0NvdW50IDIvS2lkc1sgMyAwIFIgMTcgMCBSXSA+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQozIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL1BhZ2UvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0V4dEdTdGF0ZTw8L0dTNSA1IDAgUj4+L1hPYmplY3Q8PC9JbWFnZTYgNiAwIFI+Pi9Gb250PDwvRjEgOCAwIFIvRjIgMTAgMCBSL0YzIDEyIDAgUj4+L1Byb2NTZXRbL1BERi9UZXh0L0ltYWdlQi9JbWFnZUMvSW1hZ2VJXSA+Pi9NZWRpYUJveFsgMCAwIDU5NS41NiA4NDIuMDRdIC9Db250ZW50cyA0IDAgUi9Hcm91cDw8L1R5cGUvR3JvdXAvUy9UcmFuc3BhcmVuY3kvQ1MvRGV2aWNlUkdCPj4vVGFicy9TL1N0cnVjdFBhcmVudHMgMD4+DQplbmRvYmoNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0ZpbHR
```

It outputted a huge piece to text i only posted a small chunk above.

**I tried to display the PDF like so:**

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8.....">
```

**The above did not work. I wasn't able to display the pdf file.
Any clue how I can do that?**

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:
inside of your HTTP.createServer (I assume you're doing this that way):

```
response.writeHead('Content-Type': 'maybe application/pdf');
response.write(readStream('that_pdf_file'));
```

I hope you do understand what I mean by this. Good luck.